# How to get the 1st letter of each word capital in a string of sentence using loops but not methods? in python

Tags: python, loops

```
my_str = 'peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers.'

word= ' '
out = ''

for i in range(len(my_str)):
    if my_str[i] ==' ':
    out = out + word.title()
    word =' '
else:
    word = word + my_str[I]
out = out + word.title()
print(out)
```

I am getting results using methods inside the loop... How can I get the same result using loops but not methods?

Comment: Can you use `upper`? `join`?

Comment: upper and join are..again... methods

Comment: in the meantime I provided an [answer without string methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70819951/16343464) ;) (unless `ord` and `chr` are also forbidden, which could also be solved)

Answer (score 0):

You could get the capital of a character without using a built-in method by using this function. It loops through `ascii_lowercase` and once the element of it is equal to the character you passed, it returns the element in the corresponding index from `ascii_lowercase`.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase    

def get_title(letter):
    for index in range(len(ascii_lowercase)):
        if ascii_lowercase[index] == letter:
            return ascii_uppercase[index]
```

So essentially, if you want to get the capital of each first letter, you could try this.

```
my_str = 'peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers.'
my_str += " "

word = ""
sentence = ""
for char in my_str:
    if char == " ":
        sentence += get_title(word[0]) + word[1:len(word)] + " "
        word = ""
    else:
        word += char

print(sentence)
```

Here, each word is stored when there is a space which is why a space is added to the end of `my_str` initially. After getting the word, the first element of `word` (capitalized with `get_title`) and the rest is added to `sentence`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very naive method without any string method. In summary keep a flag True on spaces. If the flag is set and you have a lowercase letter, make it uppercase. Then set the flag False.

```
my_str = 'peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers.'

out = ''
up = True

low, high = ord('a'), ord('z')
shift = ord('A') - low
for char in my_str:
    o = ord(char)
    if up:
        if low <= o <= high:
            char = chr(o+shift)
        up = False
    if char == ' ':
        up = True
    out += char

out
```

Output: `'Peter Piper Picked A Peck Of Pickled Peppers.'`

*NB. This is less efficient than using string methods, in particular due to the repeated string concatenation. Also this only works on ASCII letters.*

Answer (score 0):

`ord` is used to convert it to `unicode` and then minus that value with `32` to make it capitalize and in final step `chr` it convert back to character

```
a = 'this is awesome'
b = ''
for each in range(0,len(a)):
    if each == 0 or a[each-1] == ' ':
        x = ord(a[each])
        y = x - 32
        z = chr(y)
    else:
        z = a[each]
    b += z
```

---

## Output

```
print(b)
This Is Awesome
```